# php: How to get the unicode character from the STRING "U4e9c"?

Tags: php, unicode

This doesn't work (just echoes "U4e9c"):

```
echo mb_convert_encoding("U4e9c","UTF-8","auto");
```

I guess some sort of casting "U4e9c" is needed, but can't figure out how...

Comment: Please show the full code and the result

Comment: don't put the code in your title, it makes it difficult to copy!

Comment: Besides, mb_convert_encoding does not even exist... Use copy/paste!

Comment: greg0ire: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php; I've detailed the problem a bit further above.

Comment: Yes, mb_convert_encoding() does exist. But mb_encoding_convert() does not, that's why I'm telling you to use copy/paste. :-P

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean, I simply didn't get your answer before... (I should have looked at your reputation score first!!!)

Comment: Reminds me that this very score enables me to edit your question, which I just did ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

`echo "&#" . hexdec(str_replace("U","","U4e9c")) . ";";`

## Update

Here is where the mb_convert_encoding comes in:

```
$k = "&#" . hexdec(preg_replace("/[Uu]/","","U4e9c")) . ";";
$k=mb_convert_encoding($k ,"UTF-8","HTML-ENTITIES");
```

This allows me to UPDATE my mysql DATABASE with $k, (whereas without mb_convert_encoding it only works for DISPLAYING inside an HTML page).

Comment: And I copied and pasted it :)

Answer (score 2):

[this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#76467) provides two functions because `unicode_decode()` does not seem to exist in php5.
Here are my tests, it seems to work:

```
greg@liche :) ~ > php -a
Interactive shell

php > function unicode_decode($str){                                           
php {     return preg_replace(
php (         '#\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})#e',
php (         "unicode_value('\\1')",
php (         $str);
php { }
php > 
php > function unicode_value($code) {
php {     $value=hexdec($code);
php {     if($value<0x0080)
php {         return chr($value);
php {     elseif($value<0x0800)
php {         return chr((($value&0x07c0)>>6)|0xc0)
php {             .chr(($value&0x3f)|0x80);
php {     else
php {         return chr((($value&0xf000)>>12)|0xe0)
php {         .chr((($value&0x0fc0)>>6)|0x80)
php {         .chr(($value&0x3f)|0x80);
php { } 
php > echo unicode_decode('\u4e9c');
亜
php > echo mb_convert_encoding(unicode_decode('\u4e9c'),  "UTF-8", "auto");
亜
```

Comment: +1 this sounds more like it. I don't think `mb_convert_encoding()` is designed to deal with `\uxxxxx` symbols

Comment: Thanks for providing a working solution. But could this be condensed a bit (my unicode strings are always 4 hex digits), seems a lot of code for something seemingly straightforward?

Comment: These are functions, so you can put them in a separate file, or in a class of yours, and delete this file when you upgrade to php6. You're not obliged to copy the full code each time you want to display an unicode string. Use include() or autoload() to make sure you have access to this function or method you're going to define.

Comment: This seems to work fine:
`echo "&#" . hexdec(str_replace("U","","U4e9c")) . ";";`

Answer (score 0):

```
function utf8chr($i) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}

echo utf8chr(hexdec(substr('U4e9c', 1)));  // echo utf8chr(0x4E9C)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Unicode character in PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string)

> Because JSON directly supports the \uxxxx syntax the first thing that
>   comes into my mind is:
>
> `$unicodeChar = '\u1000'; echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');`

```
echo json_decode('"\\'."U4e9c".'"');
```