# Unicode character in PHP string

Tags: php, unicode

This question looks embarrassingly simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

What is the PHP equivalent to the following C# line of code?

```
string str = "\u1000";
```

This sample creates a string with a single Unicode character whose "Unicode numeric value" is `1000` in hexadecimal (`4096` in decimal).

That is, in PHP, how can I create a string with a single Unicode character whose "Unicode numeric value" is known?

Comment: read : http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: @diEcho: that's only for matching Unicode characters, but the OP wants to create to those characters.

Comment: this may help: http://randomchaos.com/documents/?source=php_and_unicode

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

Comment: This question is 10 years old.  The accepted answer is painfully outdated.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Because JSON directly supports the `\uxxxx` syntax the first thing that comes into my mind is:

```
$unicodeChar = '\u1000';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

Another option would be to use `mb_convert_encoding()`

```
echo mb_convert_encoding('&#x1000;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

or make use of the direct mapping between UTF-16BE (big endian) and the Unicode codepoint:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding("\x10\x00", 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
```

Comment: @Gumbo: I know that but it doesn't make any difference in here. Javascript as well as JSON support the `\uxxxx` Unicode syntax so you can use `json_decode` to work on an artifically created JSON string representation. I changed the wording though to have that clarified.

Comment: Ok, so the strict formulation of one answer to my question is:  $str=json_decode('"\u1000"');  Thank you.

Comment: I tried `echo json_decode('\u201B');` Which referes to a [*single reverted quote*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs) However it isn't working, meaning no output (even if piped to `hd`)

Comment: You need `echo json_decode('"\u201B"');`. Double quotes around the unicode symbol are mandatory.

Comment: Are there some PHP consts to use instead of the plain string `'HTML-ENTITIES'` and `'UTF-8'`?

Comment: `echo json_decode('"\u201B"');` doesn't work for me, you need double slash here as well as doublequotes: `echo json_decode('"\\u201B"');`

Comment: @IvanShatsky This shouldn't really matter: https://3v4l.org/8o0c4

Answer (score 270):

PHP 7.0.0 has introduced the ["Unicode codepoint escape" syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax).

It's now possible to write Unicode characters easily by using a [double-quoted](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) or a [heredoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string, without calling any function.

```
$unicodeChar = "\u{1000}";
```

Comment: This can be used like so: `wordwrap($longLongText, 20, "\u{200B}", true);` ([zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) it is)

Comment: I believe the OP wanted this answer, not the accepted answer. At any rate, when I searched for "Unicode in PHP", it was because I wanted this answer, not the accepted answer. Maybe "\u{abcd}" didn't exist when this question was first asked. If so, the accepted answer should now be moved.

Comment: The OP is obviously frustrated with the answers provided so suggests his own answer in a comment on the accepted answer, which may be why that is the accepted answer and this isn't. As Adam suggests, this answer is what he was looking for and given PHP version 7.1.33 was out when he asked, I suspect this would have been the accepted answer if it wasn't posted 2 years too late.

Comment: I agree with Adam, this should be the correct accepted answer now.

Comment: This works for date format strings, too. `date("l, F\u{00A0}j, Y")`

Answer (score 24):

I wonder why no one has mentioned this yet, but you can do an almost equivalent version using escape sequences in [double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

> `\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}`
>
> The sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a
>   character in hexadecimal notation.

ASCII example:

```
<?php
    echo("\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x21");
?>
```

> Hello World!

So for your case, all you need to do is `$str = "\x30\xA2";`. But these are **bytes**, not characters. The byte representation of the Unicode codepoint coincides with UTF-16 big endian, so we could print it out directly as such:

```
<?php
    header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-16be');
    echo("\x30\xA2");
?>
```

> ア

If you are using a different encoding, you'll need alter the bytes accordingly (mostly done with a library, though possible by hand too).

UTF-16 little endian example:

```
<?php
    header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-16le');
    echo("\xA2\x30");
?>
```

> ア

UTF-8 example:

```
<?php
    header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
    echo("\xE3\x82\xA2");
?>
```

> ア

There is also the [`pack`](http://php.net/pack) function, but you can expect it to be slow.

Comment: Perfect for when copy/pasting a bullet character (\xE2\x80\xA2) could result in a UTF-8 encoding error in the source document. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

PHP does not know these Unicode escape sequences. But as unknown escape sequences remain unaffected, you can write your own function that converts such Unicode escape sequences:

```
function unicodeString($str, $encoding=null) {
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding');
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/u', create_function('$match', 'return mb_convert_encoding(pack("H*", $match[1]), '.var_export($encoding, true).', "UTF-16BE");'), $str);
}
```

Or with an [anonymous function expression](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) instead of [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function):

```
function unicodeString($str, $encoding=null) {
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding');
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/u', function($match) use ($encoding) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), $encoding, 'UTF-16BE');
    }, $str);
}
```

Its usage:

```
$str = unicodeString("\u1000");
```

Answer (score 11):

```
html_entity_decode('&#x30a8;', 0, 'UTF-8');
```

This works too. However the json_decode() solution is a lot faster (around 50 times).

Comment: Simple, elegant, straightforward and totally secure method. +10

Answer (score 6):

Try [Portable UTF-8](http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8):

```
$str = utf8_chr( 0x1000 );
$str = utf8_chr( '\u1000' );
$str = utf8_chr( 4096 );
```

All work exactly the same way. You can get the codepoint of a character with `utf8_ord()`. [Read more about Portable UTF-8](http://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-unicode-to-php-with-portable-utf8/).

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by others, PHP 7 introduces native support for the `\u` Unicode syntax, thus making this question obsolete.

As also mentioned by others, for PHP 5, the easiest way to obtain a string value from a Unicode character description in PHP, is by converting it from another format (e.g. JSON or HTML entity). But, that comes at a run-time performance cost.

There is one other option, **supported in PHP 5**: You can encode the character directly in PHP with `\x` binary escaping.

This is especially useful if you prefer not to enter the character as a literal in your string. For example, if it is an invisible control character, or whitespace (hard to distinguish).

First, a proof:

```
// Unicode Character 'HAIR SPACE' (U+200A)
// Other way:
$htmlEntityChar = "&#8202;";
$realChar = html_entity_decode($htmlEntityChar);
// My way:
$phpChar = "\xE2\x80\x8A";
echo 'Proof: ';
var_dump($realChar === $phpChar); // bool(true)
```

As mentioned by Pacerier in another answer, this binary code is unique to a specific character encoding. In the above example, `\xE2\x80\x8A` is the binary coding for U+200A *in UTF-8*.

The next question is, how do you get from `U+200A` to `\xE2\x80\x8A`?

The below PHP script prints the escape sequence you need for any character.

```
/** @author Krinkle 2018 */
function str_encode_utf8binary($str) {
    $output = '';
    foreach (str_split($str) as $octet) {
        $ordInt = ord($octet);
        // Convert from int (base 10) to hex (base 16)
        $ordHex = base_convert($ordInt, 10, 16);
        $output .= '\x' . $ordHex;
    }
    return $output;
}

// Example from literal string:
// Unicode Character 'INFINITY' (U+221E)
echo str_encode_utf8binary('∞') . "\n";
// \xe2\x88\x9e

function str_convert_html_to_utf8binary($str) {
    return str_encode_utf8binary(html_entity_decode($str));
}
function str_convert_json_to_utf8binary($str) {
    return str_encode_utf8binary(json_decode($str));
}

// Example from HTML:
// Unicode Character 'HAIR SPACE' (U+200A)
echo str_convert_html_to_utf8binary('&#8202;') . "\n";
// \xe2\x80\x8a

// Example from JSON:
// Unicode Character 'HAIR SPACE' (U+200A)
echo str_convert_json_to_utf8binary('"\u200a"') . "\n";
// \xe2\x80\x8a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function unicode_to_textstring($str){

    $rawstr = pack('H*', $str);

    $newstr =  iconv('UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', $rawstr);
    return $newstr;
}
```

$msg = '67714eac99c500200054006f006b0079006f002000530074006100740069006f006e003a0020';

echo unicode_to_textstring($str);