# Function JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, function, converters

anyone can help me to convert that function JavaScript to php.

Thank you very much

```
// DECODES AND UNESCAPES ALL TEXT.
function decodeTxt(s){  
    var s1=unescape(s.substr(0,s.length-1));
    var t='';
    for(i=0;i<s1.length;i++)t+=String.fromCharCode(s1.charCodeAt(i)-s.substr(s.length-1,1));
    return unescape(t);
}

// ENCODES, IN UNICODE FORMAT, ALL TEXT AND THEN ESCAPES THE OUTPUT
function encodeTxt(s){
    s=escape(s);
    var ta=new Array();
    for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)ta[i]=s.charCodeAt(i)+encN;
    return ""+escape(eval("String.fromCharCode("+ta+")"))+encN;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the return results of `encodeTxt()` as data to PHP? Are you using a form, or do you want to use AJAX?

Comment: No, what I need is to convert these functions to PHP.

Without Encrypt text functions only work with Javascript but I need to pass it to PHP uptade make a table from a database

Comment: You should edit your question. Don't use the word "pass." Use "convert." Readers will understand better.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using google to translate

Comment: Where's the php code that doesn't work?

Comment: The code is in JavaScript, not how to do the same function but I work with PHP

Comment: This stackoverflow reference may help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string