# Checking for UTF-8 replacement character

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to determine whether or not my string contains the [UTF-8 replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Currently I've had two attempts which failed.

First attempt:

```
stristr($string, "\xEF\xBF\xBD")
```

Second attempt

```
preg_match("#\xEF\xBF\xBD#i", $string)
```

None of these works.

Question is, how can I check my string for the replacement character?

Comment: The first attempt works, assuming `$string` is encoded in UTF-8. Why do you say it doesn't?

Comment: @Joni It returns false although I can see the replacement character in my output.

Comment: Is `$string` correctly encoded in UTF-8? Remember that PHP strings can contain arbitrary binary data, if `$string` contains byte sequences that are illegal in UTF-8 the output may show a replacement character when the input has something else.

Comment: @Joni The problem is that some of the data is probably UTF-8 encoded, and some of it isn't. Checking each line, I can see that the replacement character sometimes pops up - but I cant seem to pinpoint the lines.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/476) here. I'd venture the guess that the string does not contain a replacement character, but that you're treating it incorrectly and it's displayed incorrectly in the browser. Describe your actual problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use this just to see if there are non-visible characters in a string, you could use something like this:

```
if (strlen($string) != strlen(iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $string)))
    echo "This string has invisible characters";
```

The method in your question should also work, but it requires the character encoding for the string to actually be in UTF-8. You can use `iconv` to convert a string from whatever its encoding is to UTF-8 before checking if the character is there.

Also: possibly you would want to use the multibyte notation for this character, which is \uFFFD instead. However, PHP does not support this by default, meaning you'll have to use some trick like this:

```
mb_convert_encoding('&#x1000;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058533/2394477).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if (mb_detect_encoding($str, "UTF-8") !== FALSE) {
     // $str is UTF-8 encoded
} else {
    // $str is not UTF-8 encoded
}
```

Please refer [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).