# Convert Unicode escape sequence to UTF-8

Tags: php, json, unicode

I'm trying to convert some characters with PHP before inserting to MySQL DB a JSON object with this kind of data:

```
\u00c9

that means: É
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
echo utf8_encode(print_r('\u00c9'));
```

I've read that it's in Unicode but i can't find the way to print it before inserting it. Any ideas?

Comment: Read the comment: http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#104906.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string). TL;DR:

```
echo json_decode('"\u00c9"');
```

Comment: @matuuz: Make sure you are viewing it on a UTF-8 encoded page, it does work: http://codepad.org/VlBUqdny

Comment: yeahh that was it :D thank you: <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />