# Parse.com - saving String with diacritic?

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to save this object to Parse.com database:

```
$zastavka = ParseObject::create("Zastavky");
$zastavka->set("nazov", "Bánová, Colnica");
$zastavka->save();
```

But I get "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException'..." since it looks like Parse.com is not able to handle diacritic in Strings. Is there any other way around? I need to have names of various streets in the database, therefore it is not acceptable to remove diacritic :/

Comment: I think you'd need to use the character code (á is code 160)... what language is this?

Comment: Slovak language, so I need to handle all the á, é, í, ó, ú, ý, ô, ľ, š ,č ,ť , ž.

Comment: And the programming language?

Comment: it is PHP, thank you very much for helping me out! :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that helps you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those are special characters, I'm thinking that you'll have to use their character codes instead of the actual characters. Below are unicode codes.

You will need to use these codes along with the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string). Hope that helps you!

- á --- \u00E1
- é --- \u00E9
- í --- \u00ED
- ó --- \u00F3
- ú --- \u00FA
- ý --- \u00FD
- ô --- \u00F4
- ľ --- \u013E
- š --- \u0161
- č --- \u010D
- ť --- \u0165
- ž --- \u017E

Comment: Thank you, gonna give it a try :)