# PHP eats backslashes needed in mail sequence (shared hosting)

Tags: php, escaping, email-headers

I'm aware there is a lot of topics like this one, but I wasn't yet able to find a satisfying answer.

PHP on a shared hosting where I have my webpage deletes backslashes (by using `magic_quotes()` or something like that maybe?) from expressions that are soon to be sent using `mail()`, so it changes this:

```
<?php
$email_to = "myemail@address.com";
$email_subject = "Message from your webpage";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

if($subject) {
die(); // $subject is a honeypot
}

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    die();
}

$email_message = "";
$email_message .= "Name: ".$name;
$email_message .= "Email: ".$email_from;
$email_message .= "Message: ".$message;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $name . " <" . $email_from . ">" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from;

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
```

into this:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "rn";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion()."rn";
$headers .= "From: " . $name . " <" . $email_from . ">" . "rn"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from;
```

Such emails don't have an author and without proper charset, they look terrible. I tried many different functions, but none seemed to work.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

EDIT: Ive put thw whole code in right now. Alse, var_export($headers) shows exactly whats been put in it `string(136) "MIME-Version: 1.0rnContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8rnX-Mailer: PHP/5.6.6rnFrom: dasda rnReply-To: asdasd@dasda.cz"`

Comment: try double slashes: "\\r\\n";

Comment: not working. result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Do not use their webpage editor for editing code.

There should be a code editor.

do they use cPanel as the control panel?  If so look for the code editor, it is there.

Or use FTP and edit on your local workstation. This is the preferred method.

I use FileZilla for FTP and Notepad++ as an editor, they work very well together.

**end of update**

---

You need to show the whole code as to how your are getting the "into this"
I'd like to see the var_dump if that is not what you are doing.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $name . " <" . $email_from . ">" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";

var_export($headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP's native `PHP_EOL` as it is platform-independent (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128560/2775748) for reference). Try to modify your code like this:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: " . $name . " <" . $email_from . ">" . PHP_EOL; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . PHP_EOL;
```

**EDIT:**

As @misunderstood pointed PHP_EOL would not be good solution, as e-mail headers should always be ended with  sequence.

I think, I found [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6058394/2775748) for this. Instead of `\r\n` try to use:

```
mb_convert_encoding('&#x000D;&#x000A;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: He needs CRLF not EOL.  `PHP_EOL` will give CRLF on a Windows platform, and just LF on Linux.

Comment: As i read [PHP mail docs](http://php.net/function.mail), you're right and there's no way to use any constant for that. It may be even `define('CRLF',"\r\n")`, but it doesn't resolve slash stripping problem.

Comment: You should not need a workaround, `"\r\n"` should (does) work.  What I do not understand is where they got stripped.  Where did you find "rn"?  Based on the code you posted the only place you could see the "rn" is in the received email.

Comment: Both `PHP_EOL` and `mb_convert_encoding('&#x000D;&#x000A;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')` seem to fix the problem in terms of appearing properly in `var_export($headers)` but in both cases the emails stopped coming.

Comment: Seems they get stripped as soon as I edit the file in the hostings webpage editor or upload it anew