# convert any string or a character in php to unicode code points

Tags: php, unicode, converters

How to convert any string or a character in php to "unicode code points"

for example : unicode code points of letter अ is 0905

and A is 0041

I need a continuous string if i pass Aअ which will give me a output as 00410905

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode character in PHP string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function

```
function Unicode_decode($text) {
     return implode(unpack('H*', iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-4BE", $text)));
 }
```

If you want to have `U+0000` use this :

```
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($word); $i++)
{
    $wordConvert = Unicode_decode($word[$i]);
    $result .= "U+" . substr($wordConvert, -4, 4) . "<br/>";

}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi Hearner ,

Thanks a lot its working. one more request.

if i want to make it as "U+0041" for "A" what changes can be done in this any help can be appreciated...

Comment: Its not working for multiple characters ... :)

Thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Comment: You want, for example, "AB" to be `U+0041 </br> U+0042` ?

Comment: No , Actually I want continuous string like .. 00410042 like this ..

so i , utilized the function you have given me with that .. i have divided that string by 8 characters each to make it array using "str_split" 

then using for loop made that long string. 


Thanks a lot Hearner.. your answer was very helpful to me.

Comment: No problem, I tried to make the simplest code I could :) If you need anything you can ask.