# How to use a unicode character without writing the actual unicode character?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I just stumbled over this code:

```
/**
 * @param $string
 * @return bool
 */
protected static function isRubel($string)
{
    $lString = strtolower($string);

    /**
     * @hint: The characters looking like "p" as in Petra are in fact instances of cyrillic "Er"!
     */

    return strpos($string, 'руб') !== false || strpos($string, 'р') !== false || strpos($lString, 'rub') !== false;
}
```

It was very nice of the author to provide a hint, that the character is not a `p` but a unicode symbol `р`; as I would have assumed it was a `p`.

Could this code be written differently in order to make it more clear that the character is a unicode symbol?

In a sense, write unicode representation without actually writing unicode character.

I know I could define a string constant `CRYLLIC_ER = р`, yet I was looking for a more general solution.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string

Comment: possible duplicate ^ ?

Comment: still, use a constant.

Comment: PHP doesn't support unicode, so that character is actually encoded in UTF-8. There is a simple hack to convert unicode-escaped characters into UTF-8 though, you can use `json_decode('"\u0440"')`. This is the code for your special `p` by the way.

Comment: @Havenard which is what's inside RC's link which would fall under as being a duplicate, *n'est-ce pas?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP 7 onwards you can use this syntax:

```
$str = "\u{####}";
```

Before that, you could use the UTF-8 byte values to make it dead obvious:

```
$str = "\x##\x##";
```

But personally I would do what the author did, just write it in a comment.

Comment: if so, then what RC posted would be a duplicate, *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: I *wouldn't* do what the author did.  All it takes it one errant open/save with a shoddy application to break that chunk of code.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, where I work a 'shoddy application' doing that would always have an effect on unittests, and a change would show up in a code review. If you work in a shop that's less diligent, I would agree with you... but we rely on process and tools and love embedded unicode =)

Comment: @Mr.Llama For web development, I'd consider not supporting Unicode a fatal, deal-breaking flaw in a program. *Especially in a text or HTML editor*. I'd absolutely hate having to write `caf\xc3\xa9` instead of `café`

Comment: @Evert Excactly was I was looking for, accepting the answer not your personal opionion ;)