# Converting Unicode character to text in PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unicode

I am trying to convert Unicode character to text in PHP. But the string is the mixture of Unicode characters and text. But it is not working.

I followed this link ([Unicode character in PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string))

```
<?php

   $unicodeChar = "{'singer': u'', 'name': u'\\\\u101c\\\\u1031\\\\u1011\\\\u1032\\\\u101c\\\\u103d\\\\u103e\\\\u1004\\\\u1037\\\\u103a\\\\u101c\\\\u102d\\\\u102f\\\\u1000\\\\u103a'}\\r\\n\\r\\n    artist          : Thar Gyi\\r\\n    album           : Sal Pone Ta Pone\\r\\n    genre           : R&B\\r\\n    copyright       : MyanmarSongs.NET\\r\\n    track           : 1\\r\\n    title           : Lay Htal Hlwint Lite";
   echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
   echo mb_convert_encoding($unicodeChar, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'); 
   echo mb_convert_encoding($unicodeChar, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE'); showing nothing

?>
```

All the above scenarios are not working when the value is the mixtures of Unicode characters and text like I used. But it is working when the value is so simple like this:

```
$unicodeChar = '\u1000';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: frist the json in input $unicodeChar you given not i json format. Please give me right json. so i can check it

Comment: No it come be in any format . So please how can I detect it ?

Comment: use mime_content_type function in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: My the value came from database . Not from somewhere like api. So how can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
$unicodeChar = '\u1000';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

Comment: It is working when the valus is so simple . I have updated the question.