# Convert Unicode characters to human readable string in PHP

Tags: php, string, text, unicode, unicode-string

I am having problem with converting Unicode characters to human readable text in php.

I have string of unicode characters like following

```
$chars = "\u1006\u1092\u1019\u1021\u102c\u101b\u1036\u102f \u1019\u1002\u1062\u1007\u1004\u1039\u1038 (\u1042\u1040\u1041\u1046 \u1007\u1030\u101c\u102d\u102f\u1004\u1039)";
```

If I echo like this

```
echo $chars
```

It will not convert to human readable string. But If I echo like this

```
$text = '<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("\u1006\u1092\u1019\u1021\u102c\u101b\u1036\u102f \u1019\u1002\u1062\u1007\u1004\u1039\u1038 (\u1042\u1040\u1041\u1046 \u1007\u1030\u101c\u102d\u102f\u1004\u1039)");
</script>';

echo $text;
```

It can print the human readable string like below.

[image]

Using that way I can show the result to user. But the problem is I want to store as human readable string in database. So I can do other operation with that string. So my questions are

1. How can I convert that Unicode characters into human readable string in PHP?

OR

2. How can I assign the result of the JavaScript as in second method into a string in php?

Here is the same question I asked long ago, [Converting Unicode character to text in PHP is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018194/converting-unicode-character-to-text-in-php-is-not-working).

Comment: Possibly use `mb_convert_encoding()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew . It solved my problem.

Comment: How did you get that string in the first place? As part of other text format, like JSON?

Comment: I already solved the problem.

Comment: If you solved the problem please consider upvoting the answers that proved helpful and accepting the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/iu` regex to match `\uXXXX` notation substrings capturing the digits into Group 1 that will be later used inside a `preg_replace_callback` anonymous function to [*`pack`*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) the data into a binary string. Since we pass a hexadecimal value to the `pack` function, the first argument - format character - should be `H`:

> `H`   Hex string, high nibble first

See a [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/GmvaXj):

```
$chars = "\u1006\u1092\u1019\u1021\u102c\u101b\u1036\u102f \u1019\u1002\u1062\u1007\u1004\u1039\u1038 (\u1042\u1040\u1041\u1046 \u1007\u1030\u101c\u102d\u102f\u1004\u1039)";
$encoding = ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding');
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/iu', function($match) use ($encoding) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), $encoding, 'UTF-16BE');
    }, $chars);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intl/Transliterator](http://php.net/transliterator) class:

```
$out = transliterator_create('Hex-Any')->transliterate($chars);
var_dump($out);
```

The builtin converter *Hex-Any* handles unescaping of both \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX sequences.

I don't know if it's relevant in your case, but, since PHP 7.0.0, you could write $chars this way:

```
$chars = "\u{1006}\u{1092}\u{1019}\u{1021}\u{102c}\u{101b}\u{1036}\u{102f} ...";
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 7+

As of PHP 7, you can use the [Unicode codepoint escape syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) to do this.

`echo "\u{1006}\u{1092}\u{1019}\u{1021}\u{102c}\u{101b}\u{1036}\u{102f} \u{1019}\u{1002}\u{1062}\u{1007}\u{1004}\u{1039}\u{1038}";`

outputs

`ဆ႒မအာရံု မဂၢဇင္း`.

Does that answer your question ?