# How to convert Unicode string to \u5b9d in php?

Tags: php, unicode, backslash

I really can't find any function in php to convert Unicode string to \u5b9d.  Please advise..

Comment: First result within google for unicode PHP [stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string)

Comment: Thank you but I tried to figure out how to convert from unicode string to unicode numbers.

Comment: Let me google that yor you... https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.getnumericvalue.php