# Convert unicode to its actual symbol

Tags: php, unicode

How do I convert `\u20B9` to the symbol `₹` in PHP?

I tried [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) but it is returning the same string.

Comment: `@Kumar`, that won't work.

Comment: Upgrade to php 7 and you *(in most situations)* no longer have to worry about all of this unicode stuff. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404876/797620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **json_decode** method because JSON directly supports the \uxxxx syntax

```
$unicodeChar = '\u20B9';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

For more reference try this link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: You **need** or you "can"? To my knowledge there are multiple methods to do this.