# TCPDF - superscript without HTML

Tags: tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to create PDF documents and need to render a superscript character without using HTML as the multicell option. No HTML because I need to align the words vertically at the bottom of the cell which doesn't work when the cell has HTML endabled.

Any ideas?

[Edit]

According to Jakuje's hint, I'm using this code to convert the unicode-characters:

```
$unicodeTable = array('<sup>1</sup>'=>'U+00B9', '<sup>2</sup>'=>'U+00B2', '<sup>3</sup>'=>'U+00B3', '<sup>4</sup>'=>'U+2074', '<sup>5</sup>'=>'U+2075');

function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}

function unicode_chr ($chr) {
    $x = explode("+", $chr);
    $str = "\u".end($x);
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}

foreach($unicodeTable as $uKey=>$uValue){
    $text = str_replace($uKey, unicode_chr($uValue), $text);
}
```

This works in pure php/HTML - but when I use this code with TCPDF, all I get is the unicode-code (e.g. \u00B9)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following works with TCPDF

```
json_decode('"\u00B3"') // for PHP 5.x

"\u{00B2}" // for PHP 7.x
```

Based on this stack overflow article [Unicode character in PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string)

[TCPDF 6.2.13 with PHP7.1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUd0X.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UTF8 superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block), if it is some "common" letter, such as

```
x² or xⁿ
```

Comment: I tried that. When I do it in plain HTML in works. Using TCPDF I get the unicode-code, though (like \u00B9). See my edited question for the code.