# How do I preg_replace literal unicode syntax?

Tags: php, unicode, preg-replace, unicode-literals

I have a large data set that was converted from JSON data. It has unicode characters using the JSON-compliant \uXXXX notation. I'm trying to convert these to true unicode on the fly using preg_replace.

```
preg_replace('/\\u([a-z0-9]+)/i', "\x{${1}}", $str);
```

However, this generates a warning:

PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 1

Why is preg_replace complaining when I'm searching for the actual slash-u and not a unicode literal?

Edit:

Here's what I'm working with: https://regex101.com/r/LIdECa/1

Comment: Are you trying to decode JSON manually?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The JSON data was processed and migrated into a MySQL database. These "unicode" characters remain in the text.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string, And to match a ``\`` with a regex, you need 4 backslashes. You need a preg_replace_callback, by the way, to process the match. See [**this PHP demo**](https://ideone.com/rIOC5j).

Comment: So there's a prior error, either in encoding or in decoding. In any case, I'm not sure you can generate actual characters that way because `\x` is a string literal. You'd need to verify that first.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález From what I've read, you can generate actual characters this way in PHP 7. I've never tried it before so I don't know. Getting the regex fixed was the first step in trying to make it work.

Comment: @Nilpo: A hint: you *can't* use `preg_replace` to do it unless you are not using PHP 7 and want to risk using `/e` modifier.

Comment: I'm removing my answer because it was actually not solving your problem, it included a non-working alternative and I've found a duplicate question with better solutions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I was able to get json_decode working as you suggested. I've also implemented Wiktor Stribiżew's solutions as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please post your solutions as an answer.

Comment: @Nilpo I don't think it's robust enough. If data is half-decoded (e.g. double quotes do not have the leading backslash) it'll break horribly. I suggest you use the accepted answer in the linked question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I was using that solution originally and it worked perfectly on my dev box, but not on the live server. PHP wasn't compiled with mb support.