# I can't capture a strange character with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm having problems to capture and filter out a strange character some data came with, which is causing JSON data which include it to not being correctly parsed. I don't know why, since it's not included in the white list I created with this regular expression:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w\dñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜºª\-_\/\s\\<>,;:.*\[\]\(\)+?¿!&%@=]/', '', $string);
```

Testing regular expression on [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3gamm). As you will see, this strange character is not captured
[image: Testing regular expression on Regexr]

This is how it is displayed in the browser:

[image: This is how it is displayed in the browser]

And this is how it's displayed in Pluma (a Linux editor):

[image: this is how it's displayed in Pluma (a Linux editor)]

When I copy it and try to insert it in Google, for instance, nothing is inserted. Really strange. I've never bumped into any situation like this.

Any idea on how to handle it?

Comment: @MátéSolymosi I'm using a whitelist. Those characters which won't comply with it, should be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Can you add the problematic character to the question text? I could not identify it based on the screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried simply copy and paste it into your Regex in an UTF8-Editor?

Comment: @MátéSolymosi uhm that is definitely a Whitelist.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, sorry. Didn't notice the `^` at the beginning...

Comment: @MátéSolymosi Click on the Regexr link. It will display what you see in the screen capture

Comment: @Bernhard The capture on Pluma editor is what you say

Comment: @LuisMartin I was able to copy-paste the character to the whitelist, and then it matched it without problems. I am also able to Google it.

Comment: @MátéSolymosi True! I also could. The thing is I'm forced in this case to use code edited in ISO-8859-1, which doesn't cover that character. Anyway, if it's not in the white list, it shouldn't pass the validation.

Comment: @LuisMartin Ah, I see. You could try one of these techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058533/1242470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mysterious character isn't so mysterious but is difficult to display with your editor since it is the page-breaking control character: Form Feed *(`\x0C` see the ascii table)*

This character is contained in the `\s` character class, that's why your pattern doesn't match it.

A solution consists to remove the `\s` from your pattern and to replace it with an exhaustive list of allowed whitespace characters.

To make things easier you can already put the class `\h` (if supported) that contains all horizontal whitespaces. Then add the vertical whitespaces you want by hand.

Note that if you are working with the Windows-1252 code page, keep it under the eyes to be sure not to forget anything and to shorten the pattern using character ranges.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like you answered while I was writing and posting my own answer. I found out somewhere else. Anyway. It's fair I mark yours as the accepted, instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

Turns out this character represents a [form feed](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm)

It's included in \s like white space, \t, \r or \n.

By being more specific, I achieved what I wanted. The new regex:

```
/[^\w\dñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜºª\-_\/ \r\n\\<>,;:.*\[\]\(\)+?¿!&%@=]/
```