# Convert json string to unicode

Tags: php, json, unicode, encoding

The description is a bit more complicated than the title. I'm working with some Wordpress plugins and on form submit, I want to do some work with the entry. Problem is, this is what I get as entry:

["\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647 \u06f2\u06f1 \u0645\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f\u060c \u0633\u0627\u0639\u062a \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0634\u062e\u0635"]
After searching the web for a while I figured out that this is JSON encoding, do you know how can I use PHP to reform this into unicode?
Note that the entry is a string and "\u0634" for example is not a character, but a string with the length of 6 characters.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string) may help you.

Comment: @jagad89 thank you very much it really addressed my issue

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

With `json_decode()` you can transform this json string (which represents an array with a single item) into a regular PHP array.