# Php 7 - Transform unicode string into a unicode char #emoji

Tags: php, unicode, emoji

I am trying to make a little program in Php that get a message from a text file (json) and to convert some parts into emojis.

The thing is, I just began php yesterday and since, I didn't find the solution to make it works...

I have this code :

```
$message = $_GET["message"];
$emojis = array();
echo "{$message}\n";
preg_match("({[A-Z0-9]+})", $message, $emojis);
foreach($emojis as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";
    $emoji_string = "\\u".$value;
    $emoji_unicode = utf8_encode($emoji_string);
    $message = str_replace($value, $emoji_unicode, $message);
}
echo "{$message}\n";
```

So what I am trying to achieve is, by using this regex `(\\u{[A-Z0-9]+})`, created on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), I would like to transform a simple unicode text into a emoji in order to display a beautiful message haha

So far, I understand that `\u{270B}` [#RaisedHand](https://emojipedia.org/raised-hand/) is only one char at the end, so that's why I try to convert my string into a simple char. Am I wrong? However, the code is wrong since I have `"\\u{270B}"` instead of `"\u{270B}"`...

I am really out of idea for the moment about that, any idea on your side?

Thanks for any help !

Max

## Edit 1

I tried with this message: **Hey what's up? {270B}**

output:

```
PHP
debug start
Hey what's up? {270B}
0 => {270B}
Hey what's up? \u{270B}
debug done
```

Comment: What are you getting by echoing $message

Comment: I edited for you :)

Comment: I may be very stupid but I think the problem is that \u{270B} is echoed as string and I had same problem some time long ago I may be able to find out how I did it.

Comment: I know it's encoded as string, what I am looking for is to encode it from string into a char :/

Comment: I posted answer what  is working for me :D

Comment: `utf8_encode` is a confusing name for a function, because it only does one thing: Convert a ISO-8559-1 string (latin1) into UTF-8. It's almost never what you need, and definitely not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I tested it its working for me

```
$unicodeChar = '\u1000';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058533/8517929)

Comment: Accept answer if it's working for you :D I kinda like these green notifications :D

Comment: I couldn't make it work :/ but the other anwser made it work :/ Sorry :( Thanks anyway ! :)

Comment: Well forgot to mention it I tried without **{}** but nevermind :D

Comment: Yeah :D ........ (don't know that to write so I added multiple dots to be able to send msg)

Comment: Anyway, the solution given doesn't work for all emojis... with this format `\u{1F525}`, it gives a fire, with `\u1F525` I get only `{1F525}`

Comment: Yeah, me2. If the other guy solution works better try it :D You may try to import your own fonts as emojis and then call them :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\u {270B}` doesn't exist. Right is `\u270B`. So do this:

```
<?php
$message = "message {270B}";
$emojis = array();
echo "{$message}\n";
preg_match("({[A-Z0-9]+})", $message, $emojis);
foreach($emojis as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";
    $emoji_string = "\u".substr ($value, 1, -1); //remove {}
    $emoji_unicode = json_decode('"'.$emoji_string.'"'); //decode
    $message = str_replace($value, $emoji_unicode,  $message);
}
echo "{$message}\n";
```

I tested it and it works. Output is: `message ✋`