# Unicode not working in my php

Tags: javascript, php, unicode

This is my code:

```
   $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    echo "id: ", $data['lowest_price'];
```

This is my output:

```
    id: 1,05â‚¬
```

it does not show a dollar sign as its supposed to even tho i have UFT 8 in my head?

Comment: It's valid UTF8, you're just not displaying it correctly. You should post the code that you think is setting a UTF8 content-type. Also it's a euro symbol, not a dollar sign.

Comment: Your question shows irrelevant detail (the URL from which the file is loaded). On the other hand, important information is missing: what is the text being decoded (only the piece that will result in the `lowest_price`item). May be you can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058533/2311167)