# Remove double character encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding

Using the functions [strtr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) or [str_ireplace()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) or [preg_replace()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with [array_walk_recursive()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), I try to delete the bad character encoding in a multidimensional array, the data are encoding in UTF-8 and comes from a Curl query.

I want to remove the double encoding by keeping only the correctly encoded accented character:

> ã©**é**cole => **é**cole

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ã©cole
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ã©ecole al inara avenue 2 mars casablanca
                    [1] => ã©ecole 42
                    [2] => grande ã©école
                )
        )
)
```

With PHP 7.2.6 i get an error with my code when I do this, is it a bad way to proceed?

> Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function

```
function fix_utf8(&$value, $key)
{
    $char = array('Ã©','Ã‰','Ã¨','Ãª','Ã«','Ã','à¢','Ã¹','Ã®','Ã´','Ã«','Ã¶','Ã¼','à»','Ã§','à§','Å“','â€™','â€¦','Å“','â€“','Â«','Â»','â€š');
    $value =  str_ireplace($char, '', $value);
}

$result = array_walk_recursive($result, 'fix_utf8');

print_r($result);
```

**OR**

> Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function fix_utf8(), 1 passed in

```
function fix_utf8(&$value, $key)
{
    $char = array('Ã©'=>'','Ã‰'=>'','Ã¨'=>'','Ãª'=>'','Ã«'=>'','Ã'=>'','à¢'=>'','Ã¹'=>'','Ã®'=>'','Ã´'=>'','Ã«'=>'','Ã¶'=>'','Ã¼'=>'','à»'=>'','Ã§'=>'','à§'=>'','Å“'=>'','â€™'=>'','â€¦'=>'','Å“'=>'','â€“'=>'','Â«'=>'','Â»'=>'','â€š'=>'');
    $value =  strtr(strtoupper($value), $char);
}

$result = array_walk_recursive($result, 'fix_utf8');

print_r($result);
```

**OR**

```
function fix_utf8(&$value, $key)
{
    $char = array('/Ã©/','/Ã‰/','/Ã¨/','/Ãª/','/Ã«/','/Ã/','/à¢/','/Ã¹/','/Ã®/','/Ã´/','/Ã«/','/Ã¶/','/Ã¼/','/à»//','//Ã§/','/à§/','/Å“/','/â€™/','/â€¦/','/Å“/','/â€“/','/Â«/','/Â»/','/â€š/');    
    
    $value =  preg_replace($char, '', $value);
}

$result = array_walk_recursive($result, 'fix_utf8');

print_r($result);
```

**Update:**

Precision: the CuRL request retrieves content formatted in JSON and containing Unicode characters

```
["école",["école d\u0027ingénieur"]]
```

Comment: Removing the "offending" characters will do more damage than good. Decode properly, twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use iconv_mime_decode(); PHP predefine function to remove those characters

```
<?php
$str = "ã©cole ã©ecole al inara avenue 2 mars casablanca";
echo iconv_mime_decode($str);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/284d078f3e2f68f69dc4370df895b890f349c425)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from a PHP 7.2.6 bug with Windows, the json_decode() function does not correctly convert Unicode characters included in JSON.

**SOLUTION:**

With Debian and PHP 7.0.30 the json_decode() function works correctly.

**OR**

> You can write your own function that converts these Unicode escape
>   sequences:

```
function unicodeString($str, $encoding=null) {
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding');
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/u', function($match) use ($encoding) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), $encoding, 'UTF-16BE');
    }, $str);
}
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059008/785515)

**OR**

> or make use of the direct mapping between UTF-16BE (big endian) and
>   the Unicode codepoint:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding("\x10\x00", 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058533/785515)