# How to convert unicode char to its desire value

Tags: php, character-encoding, encode

As I am trying to convert the Beyonc\u00e9 and \u00f7 to Beyoncé and ÷(division) respectively.

I have used mb_convert_encoding and iconv methods but it's not working

```php
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
echo iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT',$str);


Beyoncé and ÷
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode character in PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string)

Comment: @misorude Thank it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You question is the same as [Unicode character in PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string) and the answer is available in. You can use the json_decode method explained there.