# Export unicode data to excel in php

Tags: php, excel, unicode

İ can export json data to excel with PHP. But I use ə,ü,ç,ı,ö and so on. This caracters don`t show. 
My code:

```
$file = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;   ");
$flag = false;
foreach($output as $row) {
  if(!$flag) { 
    $arr =  implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
    $flag = true;
   }
   array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
   $arr = $arr.implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }  
  echo   $arr;
```

[image: example]

Help me please

Comment: This might be a dupe.... checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string

Answer (score 0):

Change the header to

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
```

to enforce using the UTF-8 character set.

When this does not work, please show what your filter does.

Comment: The result has not changed.

Comment: As long as you do not provide your clean function, it is hard to help.