# json_encode() returns false when I pass it non-ascii characters

Tags: php, json

When I run the following code **json_encode()** returns false (error). Does anyone know why?

```
$r = json_encode(chr(128));
var_dump($r);
```

The result is:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Why do you use `chr()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string

Comment: You don't need to guess. Invoke `json_last_error_msg()` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```php
var_dump(chr(128));
```

The `chr(128)` is a malformed UTF-8 character. [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) can't encode malformed UTF-8 characters.

#### JSON standards

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-1

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans,
> and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).
>
> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters

#### `json_encode()` with flags.

If you are running PHP 7.3 or newer, you can try this code to throw the error message.

```php
var_dump(json_encode(chr(128), JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
```

**Result:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught JsonException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.

To prevent the errors, use `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` flag but this still can not encode invalid characters.

Example:

```php
var_dump(json_encode(chr(128), JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE));
```

**Result:**

> string '""' (length=2)

#### Cleanup string.

You may clean up the string to remove any invalid/malformed characters with this code.

```php
$string = chr(128);
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
// then encode
var_dump(json_encode($string));// result is string '"?"' (length=3)
```

Comment: To also note: All JSON characters must be valid UTF-8 according to the JSON specification